# Shader vs Shader Material , papervision specific , general insight welcome

Tags: flex4, papervision3d, shader, pv3d

I asked this question on the pv3d forum and not a single person could, or cared to answer it.

Im relatively new to 3d so i apologize if this is common sense to some.

I have a sphere , in which i am applying a CellMaterial to. Looks great. 
I noticed that in the papervision sdk , there is also a CellShader.

Should I be using this in congruence with the CellMaterial ? 
Should it be one or the other ? 
Is shader , a deprecated practice to Shader Material ?

My initial thoughts were that the shader applies to the whole scene , while materials can be applied uniquely to objects.

The documentation seems to show otherwise.

What benefit if any could be gained by using both a CellShader and a CellMaterial ? id really love to get some ambient inclusion in there some how.

Answer (score 1):

If you're just after the cell look, and nothing else, CellMaterial is your choice.
The purpose of the CellShader is to mix it with a BitmapMaterial in a ShadedMaterial.

Say you apply a GaraudMaterial and like the look, but you also want a texture in there. Can't do that with a GaraudMaterial, but if you have a BitmapMaterial and a GaraudShader, you can create a ShadedMaterial that uses the two.

e.g.

```
var bitmapMaterial:BitmapMaterial = new BitmapMaterial(yourBitmapData);
var shader:PhongShader = new PhongShader(yourLight,0xFFFFFF, 0x000000,0,yourBumpMap);
//this uses the two above
var shadedMaterial:ShadedMaterial = new ShadedMaterial(bitmapMaterial,shader);
//apply it to something
var sphere:Sphere = new Sphere(shadedMaterial,250,10,10);
```

For more explanations checkout [Jim Foley's post](http://www.madvertices.com/2009/02/pv3d-shader-materials-deeper.html).

As for Ambient Occlusion, the cheapest way you can get the effect is to [bake the shadows](http://mrdoob.com/lab/actionscript/pv3d/ball_ao/) into the texture. You do that with the 3D editor of your choice(3dsmax,maya,blender,etc.), and it basically means the light/shadows are rendered into the texture.
[image: mr.doob texture baking]

There is some work on doing this [dynamically](http://kode80.com/2009/09/28/papervision-ssao-phase-ii/), haven't checked if that made into the latest version of Papervision though.

[image: kode80 ssao]